# Concating the result on another variable XQuery

Tags: xquery

I have the following Query:

```
for $b in //Desarrollador
let $desc := $b/Programa/Descripcion/text()
let $ver := $b/Programa/Version/text()
where $b/@CodigoDes = "D02"
return <salida>{$desc, $ver}</salida>
```

An the result is:

> Gestión Discos DurosImpresora32

However, what I was really want is:

> Gestión Discos 3  DurosImpresora 2

I tried to concat:

```
for $b in //Desarrollador
let $desc := $b/Programa/Descripcion/text()
let $ver := $b/Programa/Version/text()
let $result := concat($desc, $ver)
where $b/@CodigoDes = "D02"
return <salida>{$result}</salida>
```

But It shows me this error:

```
Item expected, sequence found: (text{"Gestion Discos Duros"}, ...).
```

How I could do it?

Comment: Could you make this a [MCVE]? If your engine is XQuery 3, adding a `declare context item := document { ... }` to the example, such that it contains everything needed for someone to run it themselves and see the result (and thus to check their answers) is an easy way to do that.

Comment: I'm **guessing** that a single `Desorrollador` can have more than one `Programa`, and you want the first version, then the first description, then the second version, then the second description -- but because you didn't include the data the query was run against, this is all purely guesswork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Charles Duffy mentioned in the comments, it seems like there are multiple `Programa` children in some `Desarrollador` node. This explains why `concat(...)` complains about its arguments being sequences. If that is the case, the following query should do what you want:

```
for $p in //Desarrollador[@CodigoDes = "D02"]/Programa
let $desc := $p/Descripcion/text()
let $ver := $p/Version/text()
return <salida>{$desc, $ver}</salida>
```

Comment: Thanks, was what I need. Bun now, How I can put an space between {$desc,<<<here space>> $ver}

Comment: @Sergio, try `{$desc, ' ', $ver}`.

Comment: Okey, sorry but I started a few days ago. I dont know why but I tryed that but always went wrong.